# SFTP/SCP slow uploads in Windows, Fast in Linux

Tags: windows, vps, sftp, scp, upload

I recently moved from a VPS to a reseller hosting account for my little sites and I'm having a baffling issue since: uploading files to the server is dreadfully slow. Servers are CentOS, cPanel etc, the usual hosting environment. Now we could attribute this issue to my routing, internet speed, etc, if it wasn't for this: uploading from a Linux VM is much, much faster, some upload tests:

Apps used:

Windows: WinSCP, FileZilla
Linux (VMWare): FileZilla

Upload tests:

- **From VPS to the reseller server in ssh: very fast ~20 MB/s**
- Windows 10: starts fast, few MB/s, within 2-3 seconds goes down to **~100 KB/s**
- Win10 VM, Win7 VM: same issue with minor differences
- **Linux VM (LinuxMint): 10+ MB/s**
- **Android phone with Fx Explorer, SCP (Wifi): very fast, a few MB/s**
- Asked a friend in another country to test: same issue
- Tried with a VPN in various locations: same issue

Downloads are fast in all cases, only upload seems to be affected.

With the VPS I had no issues. It was physically located much closer to me (EU/EU, now it's EU/US), but if this was the problem the tests in Linux would be the same. The main difference between the old VPS and the new server is the new one requires TLS/SSL for ftp connections.

Any ideas what I could test to find the culprit?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried [disabling the "Optimize connection buffer size" in the connection options of WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_login_connection)? This is being posted as solution to problem in transfer speed all over the place, namely in [WinSCP support forums](https://winscp.net/forum/viewtopic.php?t=25705).

Comment: yes, it makes no difference

Comment: Let me clarify, when you say a reseller hosting you mean you have kind of CPANEL or do you actually have a virtual machine in which you installed CentOS? If you have a virtual machine you can setup testing with network tools on both ends and see if its some sort of configuration that is troublesome from a Windows client.

Have you monitored the CPU usage in each situation in the "reseller" side?

Comment: I mean it's just a "reseller" package with a cPanel+WHM account, not a VPS, so I don't have much access to test anything.

Comment: One last thing, if you have shell access, doing port forwarding thru ssh (https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example) and try to download/upload this way. If it is still the same, and I'm not very confident it will be different, I'd go about it in two ways: 1st open ticket with the reseller service provider about this issue and if they don't give a solution find a new service provider and do some tests while in trial.

Comment: I don't have SSH access unfortunately. I have an ongoing ticket with the provider but so far with no results. They prepared a test VPS server in the same location to do further tests but with no conclusive results so far. The baffling here here is how it works perfectly from Linux, therefore discarding routing problems.

Answer (score 0):

I recently investigated the same problem: download speed from Windows Servers is much lower (10+ times) than from Linux servers for high-latency connections (compared Ubuntu 18.04 with Windows Server 2016, 2019, 2022). Based on my investigation and associated googling, the difference in download speed between Windows and Linux seems to be caused by different implementations of congestion control algorithm on these systems (or the difference in how it integrates into the rest of networking implementations on these systems).

See examples of similar problems and corresponding investigations on the internet:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/9d1a6fdc-3309-4c96-b02d-01b5a9c91f78/tcp-download-speed-over-high-latency-connections-is-poor-compared-to-linux?forum=winservergen

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/124907/windows-server-upload-speed-problem.html